# С какого времени слова "сегодня" и "сейчас" перестали писаться раздельно?

Tags: этимология

С какого периода времени слова сегодня и сейчас перестали писаться раздельно?

Дополнено:

Согласно фильму Глинка (1946), написание на 1836 год все еще было раздельным (см. 1:18:34)

"1836.
НА БОЛЬШОМЪ ТЕАТРЕ
Сего дня въ Пятницу, 27 Ноября,..."

Comment: prostorech, а как мы с Вами могли бы убедиться, что написание "Сего дня въ Пятницу" было модным именно в 1836 году, а не в год выхода фильма на экраны, - 1946?

Comment: @guaranteen Изыскать дополнительные источники, подтверждающие это.
Встречал такое написание еще единожды в одном из фильмов (название запамятовал)

Answer (score 1):

1) Вот текст, в которых встречаются обе формы: ***сегодня и сего дня:***

Полкамъ ***сего дня*** приказано выступить. Я **сегодня** же отсюда отправляюсь. По окончаніи сей експедиціи ожидайте отъ меня дальнѣйшихъ извѣстій.

[Фон Раан. Перечень изъ собственнаго своего журнала при завоеванїи Молдавїи и Бессарабїи съ 1787 по 1790 годъ (1792)]

**Стиль разный.** В первом случае  стиль военных приказов, во втором — общеупотребительный вариант слова.

Таким образом, мы видим, что употребляются обе формы.

2) **С какого времени?** Это сложно сказать, надо судить по текстам. В Большом этимологическом словаре (2013) указано: XI–XII век. В других источниках называются более поздние даты.

3) **Ответ на вопрос:**

1836.
НА БОЛЬШОМЪ ТЕАТРЕ
Сего дня въ Пятницу, 27 Ноября,..."

Полагаю, что раздельная форма связана с несколькими временными коородинатами: в пятницу сего дня — это в пятницу сегодняшнего дня.

4) А вот современные тексты:  А ровно там, где ей и нужно быть, ― на точке кипения самых острых страстей **сего дня** и перед своим зрителем. [Лейла Гучмазова. Драматические поиски реальности  2007]

Answer (score 0):

На чем основано мнение, что слова «сей час» и «сего дня» когда то и вдруг «перестали писаться раздельно»?

Примеры из КРЯ говорят о том что это заблуждение:

В правой печати и до сего дня излагается другая версия событий – та же, которую, как можно понять, транслирует и С.И.; ср. газету «Русский вестник», статью «К 85-летию Февральского переворота и т.н. конференции союзных стран» (http: //www.rv.ru/content.php3? [Людмила Евдокимова. Февральская революция глазами любительницы «мягких тканей и духов» (2015)]

Если результат опыта идет на пользу основной работе, то можно считать сей час не потерянным. [Сергей Смирнов. Фантасты уходят в Космос // «Знание - сила», 2006]

В дополнение к ответу, сначала приведем цитаты (из КРЯ), которые должны убедить нас, что в достаточно далеком прошлом слова « сегодня» и «сейчас» писались слитно:

«А я сейчас в печать трагедию отдам: 
Пусть судит публика!.. 
[И. И. Дмитриев. Послание от английского стихотворца Попа к доктору Арбутноту (1798)]»

«Сегодня один из тех дней свят Николаю, 
Для чего весь город пьян от края до краю ". 
[А. Д. Кантемир. Сатира V. На человеческие злонравия вообще. Сатир и Периерг (1731-1743)]»

А теперь, приведем цитаты, свидетельствующие, что и по сей день (когда это к месту) употребляются словосочетания «сего дня» и «сей час»:

«ANDREIKO (Гостевая «Локомотива», Fclm.ru) С Новым Годом! Трансферное окно открыто с сего дня? Ждём от любимого клуба подарков! [Юлия Комова. Что загадывают футбольные болельщики на Новый год? Обзор гостевых клубов российской Премьер-лиги // Советский спорт, 2012.01.02]»

«такой-то распоследний негодяй сего дня месяца года лапу приложил Теперь-то твоя душенька довольна? [Екатерина Завершнева. Высотка (2012)]»

«А ровно там, где ей и нужно быть, ― на точке кипения самых острых страстей сего дня и перед своим зрителем. [Лейла Гучмазова. Драматические поиски реальности // «Русский репортер», № 18 (18), 4-11 октября 2007, 2007]»

Во всяком случае, умел в прошлой жизни, и что-то от этого искусства сохранил по сей час. [Олег Дивов. Молодые и сильные выживут (1998)]

Приведенные примеры показывают что оба вида написания слов «сего+дня» и «сей+час» издавна мирно сосуществовали и делают это по сию пору.

Раздельное написание этих слов несет в себе оттенок возвышенности, торжественности и нет ничего удивительного, когда в театральной афише «сообщается, что «на Александринском театре, сего дня в воскресенье 19 апреля 1936 г. [К. Черевков. К возобновлению «Ревизора» // «Огонек». № 5, 1952]»

Comment: @ guaranteen, в приведенных вами примерах слова "сего дня" и сей час"  употреблены в другом значении.  До сего дня - до сих пор, до настоящего времени..  Сей час - этот час.  Автор спрашивает о словах сегодня -в нынешний день, нынче; сейчас. -В настоящее время, теперь.

Comment: Серж, мне видится, что здесь проблема не в ответе, а в вопросе, который содержит в себе ложный постулат.